# PDFBox Java - Create a PAdES Signature with external Presigned Hash

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, signature

I am able to create a valid signature using PDFBox. I'm using an external API to let my hash sign with a given Certificate this is valid.

However when using https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation there is a warning about a missing attribute.

[Validation Reposrt using EC-Europa Validation Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN0bi.png)

The current code is at: https://gist.github.com/wgnrd/e6fcb6155795014db10fd482bdb40133, but here is an excerpt of the code-snippet:

```java
PDSignature signature = createSignature(signatureAppearance.getSignerName());
SignatureOptions options = createSignatureOptions(document, signature, signatureAppearance);
document.addSignature(signature, null, options);

ContentSigner contentSigner = createContentSigner();

CMSSignedDataGenerator cmsSignedDataGenerator = createCMSSignedDataGenerator(chain, contentSigner);

ExternalSigningSupport preSignDocument = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);

CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(preSignDocument.getContent().readAllBytes());
CMSSignedData signedData = cmsSignedDataGenerator.generate(msg, false);

byte[] cmsSignature = signedData.getEncoded();
preSignDocument.setSignature(cmsSignature);
```

Is it possible to create a signature using PDFBox which passes through the validator without a warning?

The question is a continue from [PDFBox - Signing a PDF using an external service (document has been altered or corrupted)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77789725/7099387). As the answerer agreed to help me. But I would like to split this into another question so people can more easily reference to two seperate problems.

Comment: What exactly does `createCMSSignedDataGenerator`? I ask because you effectively have to customize the `SignerInfoGenerator` of the `CMSSignedDataGenerator` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337377/1729265) (scroll down for the PDFBox based example), and that method may be the best position to do that.

Comment: Ah that was my bad. I forgot to add the `createCMSSignedDataGenerator` method in the gist. I have added it now and also enhanced it with the two suggested generator classes (these are also in the gist). Unfortunately, I get an error that there isn't enough space for the signature in the pdf.

Comment: I have increased the size to 12kb using `SignatureOptions.setPrefferredSignatureSize(12288)` this now works correctly. Is this the correct approach or should this be set dynamic?

Comment: What you can do, is setting the value similar to the size of the most recently created signature container plus a few bytes. But you have to start at some value.

Comment: Alright. Yeah I can see that the signature is around that size. So I leave that just there. On another note. Using the TSA I can see that I should have a trusted source.  I'm guessing you have to pay for that kind of service since that one I'm using in the source code does return a `timeStampToken` but without any certificate chain for that TimeStamp.

Comment: *"Using the TSA I can see that I should have a trusted source. I'm guessing you have to pay for that kind of service"* - usually yes. In particular if you need a reliable timestamp service.

Comment: Ok. I see. But is there a way to locally timestamp the whole thing - even though it creates a warning?

Comment: You can locally create timestamps. Simply read RFC 3161, a time stamp essentially is a CMS signature container with a special embedded content.